# Can I set the Background of RelativeLayout to something different than a drawable in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, picasso

I am trying to change the background of my RelativeLayout in Android Studio using the .setBackground method. But it only allows to put as a value a drawable resource. The thing is that I use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for downloading pictures from imgur and loading them into an imageview and I want to use one of them as a background for my RelativeLayout. I have searched everywhere online but I can not find anything. Is it possible to set the background of RelativeLayout to the image content of an imageview which is not Drawable?

Comment: Did you try setBackgroundResource?

Comment: Yes but it still requires a Drawable value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Target to set the bitmap in RelativeLayout

```
Picasso.with(mContext).
       load(url).fit().
       into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    relativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmap));
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: I understand nothing but it works. Thank you so much for your help. I will study more on this to see how it  works. Java saves my friend :)